# Selecting records between 2 dates with sqllite

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have some data in a sqllite db of the form:

```
id  column1  date
111 280 1/1/2014
112 281 invalid invalid invalid
113 282 invalid invalid invalid
114 275 1/2/2014
......................
338 273 1/31/2014
```

I want to select all the records in January. the date column has the form mm/dd/yyyy . The Kicker is that there are some intervening records that are invalid and don't have a date. I want to select these as well, so that I end up with all the records between id 111-338

All the columns except for id are in text format.

How can I do this?

Comment: can you show how those invalid dates look like? is date a varchar field then?

Comment: `there are some intervening records that are invalid` ... actually _all_ the dates look invalid.  Never store dates as text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not bulletproof but worth a try.

```
select  *
from    t
where   cast (substr(date,1,instr(date,'/')-1) as int) in (0,1)
;
```

Comment: Thank you, that is fantastic. I will have to read more about cast, substr, and instr

Comment: Instr() returns the position of a string within another string, Substr() returns a portion of another string (used in conjunction, those two together say _get me this starting wherever that is_), and Cast(), naturally, casts the results of the substring into a different type.

Answer (score 1):

> the date column has the form mm/dd/yyyy

This is your problem.  You should be using yyyy-mm-dd format, which sorts in lexicographic order and is compatible with [SQLite date and time functions](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html).

Comment: And that goes for all databases (and programming in general), not just sqlite.  Anything not in that ISO format should be for presentation purposes only.

Comment: @jd134679 actually that is not relevant to most of the databases since they support date types.